# Left vs right degree of skew-field extensions

Tags: division-algebras

Artin in his book, Geometric Algebra, says the connection between the left
degree and right degree of a skew-field extension is unknown.
Since I'm not an expert, I was wondering if someone knew the answer to this question. The book is rather old and there must have been some developments since that time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything that might happen does happen.

In

*Schofield, A. H.*, [**Artin’s problem for skew field extensions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100062538), Math. Proc. Camb. Philos. Soc. 97, 1-6 (1985). [ZBL0574.16008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0574.16008).

it is shown that for any integers $m,n>1$ there is a skew field extension with left degree $m$ and right degree $n$.

Cohn had previously proved the corresponding fact for an arbitrary pair of cardinals (greater than $1$) under the assumption that at least one is infinite.